# C# Loop which waits for variable to change is not working

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I have 2 loops, one loop which goes on forever and another inside that loop, its supposed to wait for the variable "month" to change. Heres the code

```
int monthc = 0;
while (true) {
            monthc = time.month + 1;
            while(monthc != time.month){
            Debug.Log (monthc + " " + time.month);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f);
        }
        monthc = 0;
            payment = loan * interest;
            money.Money = money.Money - payment;
        }
```

If you are wondering what yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.1f); its kind of the same as thread.sleep(100);.

Not sure if the time class is needed so I will just include it anyways;

```
public static int daytime = 1;
public static int month = 1;
public static int year = 1;
public static float speed = 2f;

Text text;
IEnumerator Time(){
    while (true) {
        daytime++;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (speed);
        if (daytime == 31) {
            daytime = 0;
            month++;
        }
        if (month == 13) {
            year++;
            month = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I will also enjoy any feedback to make it more efficient.

Comment: where is time.year  being incremented?

Comment: What's wrong with `Thread.Sleep(100);` or even better `await Task.Delay(100);`?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Why are you using a delay rather than synchronization primitives?

Comment: Add a break point and you can easily observe the behavior described in `user1666620`'s answer. Also what the hell are you trying to do here? How can we give "feedback to make it more efficient" when your code is just a giant infinite loop?

Comment: @xxbbcc Threading in unity is terrible.

Comment: @CalebB so gigantic infinite loops are better? as Trevor Pilley said in his comment, use `Thread.Sleep` or the `await` functionality.

Comment: @user1666620 Thread.Sleep would stop the whole program, I agree that huge infinite loops suck, but threading in Unity is even worse.

Comment: @CalebB How is threading in Unity terrible? If Unity has true threads (if that's indeed what you need) then I fail to see how they're terrible if you can use methods of `Thread` with them. `Thread.Sleep` and the like is almost guaranteed to be incorrect, _especially_ in a game if that's what you're working on.

Comment: @xxbbcc The Unity api is not thread safe, which makes it difficult but possible.

Comment: @CalebB Very few full API-s are thread safe - much of the .NET framework is not thread-safe either. If you use multiple threads, you need to use proper synchronization. I don't see how this makes Unity threading different from any threading I've seen before. (I don't have much experience with Unity.)

Answer (score 2):

At least one of your problem is here:

```
monthc = time.year + 1;
    while(monthc != time.year + 1){
    ....
```

You are changing `monthc` to be equal to `time.year + 1`, so they are always going to be equal and so will never enter the inner while loop.